# Django CKEditor different toolbar settings for django admin

Tags: django, ckeditor

Is there any way to set the different CKEditor toolbar settings for the Django Admin Panel with django-ckeditor.

My toolbar settings in settings.py looks as below

```
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Image', 'Youtube', 'Smiley',
             'Undo', 'Redo', 'Preview', 'Source'],
        ],
```

I want to set just ['Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Undo', 'Redo'] for non-admin pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Reference [here](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor).

In settings.py:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': 
            ['Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Image', 'Youtube', 'Smiley',
             'Undo', 'Redo', 'Preview', 'Source'],
    },
    'non_admin':{
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': 
            ['Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
    },
}
```

and in models.py:

```
content = RichTextField(config_name='non_admin')
```